# multiline not recognised

Tags: environments, amsmath, texshop

I am trying to use multiline with Xelatex in Texshop but this is what happens when I do. This is a minimal document:

```
>\documentclass{amsart}  
\usepackage{amsmath}  
\begin{document}  
\begin{multiline}  
    a+b+c+d+e+f=g\\  
    l+m=n  
\end{multiline}    
\end{document}
```

And the console output is:

> ```
> This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99996 (TeX Live 2016) (preloaded format=xelatex)
>  restricted \write18 enabled.
> entering extended mode
> (./mwe.tex
> LaTeX2e <2016/03/31>
> Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 83 language(s) loaded.
> (/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amscls/amsart.cls
> Document Class: amsart 2015/03/04 v2.20.2
> (/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
> For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
> (/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
> (/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
> (/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
> (/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
> (/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd)
> (/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty))
> (./mwe.aux) (/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd)
> (/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd)
> ./mwe.tex:5: LaTeX Error: Environment multiline undefined.  
> See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.  
> Type  H <return>  for immediate help.  
>  ...                                                
>  l.5  \begin{multiline}
> ```

I suspect I am doing something silly but I would be very glad to be told what.
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Silly indeed: the environment is `multline`, not `multiline`.

Comment: Thanks, Bernard. Very silly indeed. But it really should be multiline, I think.

Comment: I might set a confusion when people speak of multiline equations in general: align, gather, cases, alignat are also multiline equations, in the generic sense.

Comment: I am feeling a bit less silly now. I knew I had seen multiline somewhere.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as it was about a simple typo.

Comment: Not a typo: I meant to type 'multiline'. More of a mindo.

Comment: I would keep it open, it helped me